# How do i get identity token in paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I don`t know where is the identity token on paypal sandbox.
is the identity token same like api number ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Visit the Profile via www.sandbox.paypal.com, then go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website, turn on "auto return" and "payment data transfer" and then the identity token will appear under "Payment data transfer".

[image]

If it does not display PDT token then try to purge cookies related to *.paypal.com and try the same process again. I solved this issue by following this. I found this from comment for this answer.

Comment: When i'm trying to activate PDT from my developer paypal account following your direction i get this error: 

Checkout settings

You haven't created any settings for making small purchases (less than €4,00 EUR) that don't require shipping.

Comment: When I tried to do this, it said "Bad request." Header size has exceeded browser limit.  COOKIE /n.  I am using Chrome as my browser. Is there some way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you purge your *.paypal.com cookies and try again? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en

Comment: 2019 March update : UI changed , this is the direct url https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website#

Comment: I had an issue, that Identity Token was not showed at all, even though Payment Data Transfer was ON. What I did, I simply disabled that option and enabled again. Then token appeared below Payment Data Transfer text. Seems their website is a bit buggy.

Answer (score 6):

PayPal has updated their UI a bit. To save you some time filtering through the clutter here is the current location to generate an identity token.

Profile > My selling tools > Locate 'Website preferences' then click Update

[image: paypal profile screenshot]

Comment: This is the direct url https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website#

Answer (score 5):

With new look, i managed to access it by going to this link:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments

and seller preferences is located here:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES

Answer (score 2):

PayPal has some troubles with generating PDT tokens in sandbox.

For now you need to post your request in the following thread, providing your sandbox merchant id:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/PDT-Token-in-Sandbox/td-p/1617493