# PayPal identity token not showing on sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is there any reason why the PayPal identity token shows for some folks and not for others when using the sandbox testing environment.

I am using the API in the United Kingdom and cannot for the life of me generate or find the token.

I have followed the protocol and created a viable return url, turned on payment data transfer etc etc.

[image: pdt]

I have also looked at the stack answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961544/how-do-i-get-identity-token-in-paypal-sandbox) and still cannot see it.

What do I need to do to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue despite having added my auto return url.

Turns out, you need to turn it off after adding your auto return url and then back on again in order to see the identity token.

When you turn it on again, it shows up.

Answer (score -3):

I'm having the exact same issue. I found the key by going into Incognito mode and turning it off and on again.

Seems like maybe an ad-blocker stopping it from working.